# Remove Expensed Opportunity Product from Totals

Tags: visual-workflow, opportunity

I have a checkbox to indicate that the product is expensed and I am wondering about strategy to exclude the expensed product from the opportunity product total and the opportunity amount. The primary concern is probably opportunity amount as the expensed product is not revenue. The preference from the business is not to create any new fields because of the number of reports that have already been created.

Comment: A downvote without an explanation is the polar opposite of helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using it already, you could use the Discount field to achieve this. A Record Triggered Flow that is fired when your checkbox is marked as true would be able to see it to 100%, which in turn will set the Opportunity Product Total to 0 and mean that it doesn't flow up into your Opportunity Total Amount.